# Why isn't my applet initializing in Face Book games?

Tags: 10.10, flash, applet, games, browser

Whenever I want to play games on face book I have to use windows. I cannot get the applet to initialize on Ubuntu. I have my drive partitioned to use both. Any ideas will be most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a game that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't have Flash Player installed. I'd expect Firefox and even Facebook to be screaming that out to you, but just in case you don't have it, here's how to install it.

If you're on 32bit, run:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

If you're on 64bit, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sevenmachines/flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin64-installer
```

Restart Firefox and it should work.

Comment: And flashplugin-installer is part of the ubuntu-restricted-extras package which also includes various codecs - well worth adding the lot provided that you're in a country that has no legal issue doing so.